# using mini-css-extract-plugin and style-loader together

Tags: webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am new to that webpack thing and following some tutorials to learn basics.

I would like to use `style-loader` to inject stylesheets during development (with HMR enabled) and want to use `MiniCssExtractPlugin` for production builds. But when I use MiniCssExtractPlugin plugin, I loose injecting feature of style-loader.

Please see my webpack config :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                   {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
                        }
                    },
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 3000
    }
};
```

Comment: "But when I use MiniCssExtractPlugin plugin, I loose injecting feature of style-loader" - what do you mean? in the previous sentence you mentioned that you want `style-loader` in `dev mode` & `MiniCssExtractPlugin` in `prod mode`. Your requirement is not clear. Kindly clarify

Answer (score 10):

The second parameter of the function assigned in `webpack.config.js` to `module.exports` contains the **mode** flag (`--mode [development|production]`). So here you can use the **mode** to load `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` or `style-loader`.

While developing, using `style-loader` is faster than extracting the styles each time. But in production, you should extract the styles in separate files to avoid the loading glitch in your web, when the styles load after the HTML, and you see your page without styles for a moment.

```js
module.exports = (_, { mode }) => ({
  // other options here
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules here
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          mode === 'production'
            ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
            : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations about what the code in your answer does and why it should solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

[MiniCssExtractPlugin says](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) actually you cannot do that:

> This plugin should be used only on production builds without style-loader in the loaders chain, especially if you want to have HMR in development.

Answer (score 3):

if you like to use a specific loader for one dev environment and another one for production then i suggest that you [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) , which will allow you to write two separate webpack configuration files based on the env.mode varriable 
here is an example :

this is my main webpack config file :

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");

const modeConfig = env => require(`./build-utils/webpack.${env}`)(env);

module.exports = ({ mode } = { mode: "production" }) =>
  webpackMerge(
    {
      mode,
      entry: ['./src/index.js'],
      output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        })
      ]
    },
    modeConfig(mode)
  );
```

As you can see in line 6 i have declared a modeConfig variable that is a function that returns the value of require based on the env varriable passed through the cli command.

And now Create your webpack.production.js under build-utils folder 
this folder is going to contain just the config for the production evn :

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
   module.exports = () => ({
        module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
   });
```

Next your Dev config file

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = () => ({
            module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                           loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                           options: {
                             hmr: true // since u know this is dev env
                           }
                        },
                        "css-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
          contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
          compress: true,
          hot: true,
          port: 3000
         }
       });
```

Now all you need is run the command

```
webpack --env.mode=production
```

or

```
webpack --env.mode=development
```

Comment: To minify the CSS 3 and the Javascript files in production I needed to import `const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");` and set it on `optimization: {
    minimizer: [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
  },`, otherwise only the CSS 3 files were minified